# Sql create table statement for address

Tags: sql

For this problem, I have to make sure the address and the coordinates are unique. What I have right now is something like:

```
address (address_id, street_number, street_name, apt, city, state, zipcode, x_cords, y_cords)
```

where `address_id, street_number, street_name, apt, city, state, zipcode` are all primary keys  and   `x_cords, y_cords` are unique.

But with this, I have the problem of what if the address is of an apartment building where there can be multiple apartments stacked on top of each other, by making both the cords unique I am making sure that they are never repeated again for any address. So if one apt is added, another apt at the same location cannot be added at the top or the bottom because the x and y cords will be the same. Are there any suggestions to make this work, where both the address and coordinates are unique?

Comment: I believe you will need a separate table for the coordinates of the constructions and associate the constructions with the coordinates, so that all units of the same construction have the same coordinates.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: You will have to be very sure about the source data, too.  What about 123 Pretty Lane Apt A vs 123 Pretty Ln Apt A vs 123 Pretty Lane Apt-A vs 123A Pretty Lane vs 123 Pretty Apt A.  Addresses can be written so many ways unless the input is strictly validated, and probably even then you can sneak some variations through.

Comment: Would be a shame not to include this link...https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

Comment: The design is the problem here. You even have name in your table. That means that something like roommates can't both in this table because they would have the same address.

Answer (score 1):

Try set only address_id as primary key and set unique (address_id, apt,zip_code,x_cords, y_cords) with constrain definition like this example:

```
CREATE TABLE address (
 address_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 number INT(10) NOT NULL,
 apt INT(10) NOT NULL,
 name varchar(255),
 city varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 state varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 zipcode varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 x_cords varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 y_cords varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT APT_ADDRESS UNIQUE (address_id,apt,zipcode,x_cords,y_cords)
);
```

with this, you have an index and a unique set of fields that validate your data